# Outputting Value of Promise during multiple parses

Tags: d3.js, promise, angular2-services

I am loading a promise from d3.csv and then making multiple changes to the returned array in subsequent .then calls.

I need to out put to the html (Angular 2) the sate of the array before each change, I can do this using the ( variable | async ) but it will update with each change and I need to output the state before each change.

I tried to clone the promise, but all clones just point to the same promise. Any variables are out of scope in the changes, and the parent scope is not reachable.

```
data = d3.csv promise
data.then(methodB()). // HTML | async Output Required of Array before changes
then(methodB()) // HTML | async Output Required of Array before changes
etc..
etc..
etc..
(There are around 15 methods applied to the data as it is munched and analyzed)
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: So are the changes cumulative, or is each change based on the same original array?

Comment: cumulative, each change is additive to the previous change, and each change is dictated by selections in the U.I. before processing (Normalization vs Standardization for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming :

- you have a starting promise named `csvPromise`, which delivers array
- the methods to be applied are `methodA`, `methodB`, `methodC` etc, each of which accepts Array
- each method either returns a mutation of the input array or delivers the mutation via a Promise
- changes to the array are cumulative, method-on-method
- you have a synchronous function `output()` which will accept the original array and each mutation

then a pattern like this will do the job :

```
csvPromise
.then(function(arr) {
    output(arr); // observe initial array as delivered by csvPromise
    return methodA(arr);
})
.then(function(arr) {
    output(arr); // observe array after application of methodA
    return methodB(arr);
})
.then(function(arr) {
    output(arr); // observe array after application of methodB 
    return methodC(arr);
})
etc..
etc..
etc..
.then(function(arr) {
    output(arr); // observe array after application of final method
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error); // any error thrown from anywhere in the chain will arrive here 
});
```

The pattern can be proceduralised by building the chain dynamically as follows :

```
var methods = [methodA, methodB, methodC, ...]; // list of methods (uncalled at this point)
return methods.reduce(function(promise, method) {
    return promise.then(function(arr) {
        output(arr); // observe result of previous stage
        return method(arr);
    });
}, csvPromise)
.then(function(arr) {
    output(arr); // observe array after application of final method
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error); // any error thrown from anywhere in the chain will arrive here 
});
```

The most likely violation of the assumptions would be that `output()` was itself *asynchronous*, in which case :

```
var methods = [methodA, methodB, methodC, ...]; // list of methods
return methods.reduce(function(promise, method) {
    return promise.then(function(arr) {
        return output(arr).then(function() {
            return method(arr);
        });
    });
}, csvPromise)
.then(function(arr) {
    output(arr); // observe array after application of final method
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error); // any error thrown from anywhere in the chain will arrive here 
});
```